# Распечатать данные горизонтально в PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Используя PHPExcel я пытаюсь сгенерировать файл с именами и проектами полученными из базы данных. У меня получается распечатать вертикально имена, но я хочу, чтобы названия проектов распечатывались в виде заголовков горизонтально.
На данный момент названия проектов печатаются вертикально.
Вот, что имеется на данный момент:

```
<?php
require_once ('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
include('inc/database_connection.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME); 

$output='';

if (isset($_POST['export_excel']))
{
    $sql="SELECT username  FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";

    $sql2="SELECT * FROM project";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    if (!$result2) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }   
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result2))
    {  
        $title[] = $row2['title'];
    }   

            //echo '<th>'.$ttl.'</th>';


    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        if(isset($title))
        {
            foreach($title as $ttl)
            {
                $output .= '
                            <table class = "table" bordered = "1">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>'.$ttl.'</th>
                                </tr>


                ';
            }
        }
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $output .= '
                        <tr>
                            <td>'.$row["username"].'</td>
                        </tr>


            ';
        }
        $output .= '</table>';
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="projects.xls"');
        echo $output;
    }
}
?>
```

Имена печатаются вертикально, мне необходимо распечатать горизонтально названия проектов. Как это иожно сделать? Спасибо

Comment: Причем здесь PHPExcel, если вы выводите html?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я использую PHPExcel чтобы сгенерировать Excel файл из полученных данных.

Comment: Я вижу пример, в котором выводится html-таблица, которая выдается с content-type экселя, но нет ни одного вызова PHPExcel

Comment: Или это какой-то другой или не полный пример

Comment: @DmitryKozlov почему тогда у меня получается сохранить этот код как excel файл?

Comment: Видимо - это сам excel преобразует табличные данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже выше отметили комментаторы, Ваш скрипт некорректно формирует экселевский документ.

Отличная статья на тему работы с PHPExcel на русском представлена [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/245233/).

Попробуем на основе указанной выше статьи чуть переделать Ваш скрипт. Честно говоря, не понял как должны быть связаны имена пользователей и имена проектов, так что не судите строго.

```
<?php
require_once ('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
include('inc/database_connection.php');
$conn = mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USER, DATABASE_PASSWORD, DATABASE_NAME); 

// Подключаем Excel2007.php
require_once('PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');
// Создаем объект класса PHPExcel
$xlsx = new PHPExcel();
// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
$xlsx->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Получаем активный лист
$sheet = $xlsx->getActiveSheet();
// Подписываем лист
$sheet->setTitle('Имя листа');
// Стиль заголовка
$HeadStyle = array
    (
        'fill' => array
            (
            'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array
                (
                'rgb' => 'EAF1DD'
                )
            ),
        'font' => array
            (
            'bold' => true
            ),
        'borders' => array
            (
            'top'     => array
                (
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array
                    (
                    'rgb' => '808080'
                    )
                ),
            'bottom'     => array
                (
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array
                    (
                    'rgb' => '808080'
                    )
                ),
            'left'     => array
                (
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array
                    (
                    'rgb' => '808080'
                    )
                ),
            'right'     => array
                (
                'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,
                'color' => array
                    (
                    'rgb' => '808080'
                    )
                )
            ),
        'alignment' => array
            (
            'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
            'vertical'   => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
            'wrap'       => true
            )
    );

if (isset($_POST['export_excel']))
{
    $sql="SELECT username  FROM user ORDER BY username ASC";

    $sql2="SELECT * FROM project";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
    if (!$result2) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
    }   
    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array( $result2))
    {  
        $title[] = $row2['title'];
    }

    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if(!$result || mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
        if(isset($title))
        {
            $Column=0;
            foreach($title as $ttl)
            {
                // Записываем в ячейку имя проекта
                $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($Column,0,$ttl);
                // Задаём ячейке стиль заголовка - цвет, шрифт, границы, центрирование
                $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($Column,0)->applyFromArray($HeadStyle);
                $Column++;
            }
        }
        $Column=0;
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            // Записываем в ячейку имя пользователя
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($Column,1,$row["username"]);
            $Column++;
        }

        // Выводим заголовки
        header ( "Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT" );
        header ( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT" );
        header ( "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
        header ( "Pragma: no-cache" );
        header ( "Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" );
        header ( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"projects.xlsx" );

        // Выводим содержимое файла
         $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($xlsx);
         $objWriter->save('php://output');      
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: В каждом проекте имеются процессы, каждый человек привязан к каждому процессу. Я хочу вывести имена и процессы к которым привязан каждый человек в каждом проекте. Спасибо за ссылку и переделанный пример. Один вопрос что такое `$i` внутри `getStyleByColumnAndRow($i,1)`?

Comment: Я так понмиаю это column, но где Вы ее обозначаете

Comment: Да, всё верно, это должен был быть $Column. Спасибо что указали на ошибку, исправил.